Is there locally produced bryndza in Britain?
I can order Slovak bryndza in Britain but I am curious if there is locally produced, as there are much sheep in Britain.
Where can I buy locally produced sheep cottage cheese in Britain?

It's not a common product in the UK, and from what I can find there is the odd farmer that makes similar products, but they are highly localised, artisan products, and unlikely to show up in common supermarkets. Your best bet might be to find a sheep farmer and/or cheese maker close to you and see if they can make you some. Either way it could likely be more expensive or worse quality than importing it.

To emphasise what @Plutian says, I’ve never seen sheep cheese at a ‘regular’ supermarket, but if you haven’t I’d check out your local Polish / Eastern European shop - it won’t be locally produced, but it may be cheaper than importing yourself.

I don't know if there's a prejudice against sheep's milk products in the UK. I sometimes used to buy Fage brand sheep's milk yoghurt in my local supermarkets, but I never see it any more - only the cows' milk version.
